# does ggplot2 require dataframes for proper plotting?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plot of 30 data points by day. Yet when I do this I end up with a lot more plot points than I have data. I didn't convert harMetDaily.09.11 to a dataframe. If I do this as a line instead of a line with 30 points it shows hundreds and looks really not smooth - given the problem is in all kinds of plots I assume it is in my data formatting. The plots themselves have the correct x and y axes and labeling and formatting -- this is just in the data display

```
# daily HARV met data, 2009-2011
harMetDaily.09.11 <- read.csv(
  file="C:/Users/12083/Documents/orbis/NEON-DS-Met-Time-Series/HARV/FisherTower-Met/Met_HARV_Daily_2009_2011.csv",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# convert date to Date  class
harMetDaily.09.11$date <- as.Date(harMetDaily.09.11$date)

## ----plot-chat-----------------------------------------------------------

chatdaily <- ggplot(harMetDaily.09.11, aes(date, chat)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Daily Library Transactions") +
  xlab("Date") + ylab("Transactions") +
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format ("%m-%y"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold",
                                  size = 20)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=18))

chatdaily
```

Comment: please make an example where we have access to the data to help you. Also it would be good to actually see the plot you have made so we can understand what is going on. Currently, it is impossible to understand what your data looks like or the corresponding plot.

Comment: I put all of that on github including the plot https://github.com/karl1776/graph

Comment: i'd double check the contents of your csv, you have more than 30 rows for the data you've uploaded to github. you can always filter it to first 30 rows by replacing `ggplot(harMetDaily.09.11, aes(date, chat))` with `ggplot(head(harMetDaily.09.11, 30), aes(date, chat))`

Comment: That makes sense that you would want to limit the plot to data points that are actually there. Unfortunately that change makes new errors Cannot add ggproto objects together. Unexpected comma -- whole thing just blew up. All I want to do is chart number of chats by day of the week and by month and by year. Not sure why is so difficult

Comment: I understand plotting. If I had to just graph some numbers within R I could do that.  I think the issue here is something to do with getting the dates properly formatted from their import from excel. I have a book on order about that.

Answer (score 0):

To me it does not look like the plot is plotting more than it should.

below is a reproducible example, and I also omit all data rows without a date, just to check. there are 341 rows with valid date, and the plot to me looks about right.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data_url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karl1776/graph/master/Met_HARV_Daily_2009_2011.csv"


dt <- url(data_url) %>% 
  read.csv(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(date)) 

ggplot(dt, aes(date, chat)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Daily Library Transactions",
       x = "Date",
       y = "Transactions") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%m-%y")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold",
                                  size = 20),
        text = element_text(size=18))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>